# Very slow parsing in AVD

Tags: android, performance, parsing

My code gets a RSS feed and parses it. Code works fine, but is very slow in some functions (see time in code). Any suggestions?

```
        URLConnection connection = feedUrl_.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream(); // 15 sec

        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(reader);
        doc = builder.parse(inputSource); // 60 sec
```

Comment: it's always slow for me... I prefer to execute to a device (using eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buddy , try using XMLPullParser to parse data , it won't take much time to parse data hardly 6-7 secondes. Here is the code . Try this out:

```
onCreate()
{
try 
  {

  URL url = null;
  url = new URL("http://feeds.abcnews.com/abcnews/worldnewsheadlines");
  XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
  factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
  XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
  xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");
  boolean insideItem = false;

        // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    insideItem = true;
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        headlines.add(xpp.nextText()); // extract the
                                                        // headline
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        links.add(xpp.nextText()); // extract the link of
                                                    // article
                }
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG
                    && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                insideItem = false;
            }

            eventType = xpp.next(); // move to next element
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

      public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
    try {
        return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope this will example will help you out. :)

Comment: Man, it is realy faster! Thanx, will use it

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be the emulator itself, since it has performance issues. I suggest that you test it on an actual device to determine whether the problem comes from the emulator or from the code.

If testing on a device is not possible for you at the moment, answers to this SO question suggest many tips to improve the emulator : [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com) , it's very speedy and you can access to logs via adb.